# Facebook iOS SDK only compiling for armv7

Tags: ios, armv6, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to use the facebook-ios-sdk in an iPhone application. I followed the setup instructions and it works perfectly on the simulator, but I cannot get it to run on my actual device. I am using Xcode 4.3 and my deployment target is 3.1 (with ARC).

When I try to run the application on the device, it complains that it cannot link the facebook-ios-sdk since the statically linked library (as per suggestion when using ARC) does not support armv6? According to the facebook-ios-sdk page it does however support it.

Is there a different way to compile the linked lib than described on the facebook-ios-sdk page to include armv6?

Comment: yes, just see your project settings, search for armv7 and armv6, the new xcode is silly im some ways

Comment: My project settings are correct to work with both armv6 and armv7. When I remove the facebook-ios-sdk it runs on my phone fine, but when it tries to link the facebook-ios-sdk universal library, it complains that that library does not have armv6 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what rogchap mentioned, is the value of Valid Architectures "armv6 armv7" in the Build Settings for your facebook-ios-sdk project?

And just to be sure, my Architectures setting reads as follows without the quotes:

"armv6 $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)"

Answer (score 3):

Open `facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeprodj`, then in Build Settings -> Architectures add `armv6`.
Build/rebuild the static library via the included script:

```
./scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

The Library should now work with `armv6` and `armv7`

Comment: As soon as I add `armv6` the script does not compile : "No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv6 armv7, VALID_ARCHS=i386)"

Comment: Thanks, in combination with answer from @Steven it worked, but his was more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint: check your info.plist file for the key 'required device capabilities' and make sure that there is no value like 'armv7'. That would exclude armv6 devices.